# Reading Python database in Excel

Tags: python, database

I would like to please know the way you think / get some ideas on how to approach this.

Basically I am creating a database using Python.
Everyday I load more data to several tables in a .db file.

The issue is that I have some users that want to have access to this data in Excel, to then work it their own way.

My question to you is: do you usually create databases in Python and then save them on a .csv file, that is then read by Excel?

Or do you save the data on a .db file or access file, that is then read by Excel?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you storing data on a .db file ?!

Create a real database via MongoDB / MariaDB / Postgresql / or so more ... On a virtual machine or in a docker container.

By this way if you let a server run, then people can access it !

You can use SQL Alechemy which is a great library : https://www.sqlalchemy.org for accessing, creating, modifying, and so more your database. There are others libraries available you just have to search depending of your need !

And to write in a .csv file just look the official documentation of Python ! Open and Write ! https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html

Comment: Hi @Da2ny,
Thank you very much. I just wanted an answer like yours.
Basically this is legacy work that was stored in .db and I wished to understand what do people usually go for.